# Isp of LOX-based hybrid rocket engines

Tags: hybrid-rocket

Can anyone help to find data or book on Isp for hybrid rocket engines **using LOX** as oxidizer?

I am interested to know Isp for LOX combinations with carbon, Al+HTPB, parafin, sugar and others.

Comment: Book recommendations or questions asking for resources outside the site are considered off-topic. is there a specific question? Furthermore, have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_rocket_propellant, especially the tables?

Comment: None of the propellants in that table correspond to those mentioned by OP.

Comment: http://www.spg-corp.com/hybrid-rocket-propulsion.html claims 340s for paraffin-LOX at 70:1, but I don't know if that's even plausible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's [some information from Delft University](http://www.lr.tudelft.nl/nl/organisatie/afdelingen/space-engineering/space-systems-engineering/expertise-areas/space-propulsion/propulsion-options/chemical-rockets/hybrid/) with a table showing 275-300s specific impulses for various HTPB and PE hybrids.

Here's a [nice hybrid overview paper](http://www.eucass-proceedings.eu/articles/eucass/pdf/2012/01/eucass2p353.pdf) with a broader table, giving LOX-carbon Isp 249s, LOX-HTPB/Al 40% Isp 274s, LOX-paraffin 281s. These figures are all for chamber pressure of 3.5MPa (~35 atmospheres), exhausting at sea level pressure, but expansion ratio not specified.

The closest thing in the latter table to sugar is cellulose, which gives 247s burned with gaseous oxygen. (Sucrose is C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>12</sub>O<sub>6</sub>, sorbitol is C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>14</sub>O<sub>6</sub>, cellulose C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>10</sub>O<sub>5</sub>.)